# Python IMAP search not updated

Tags: python, imap

I want to use python `imaplib` to receive mails automatically, but it doesn't update after I send a new mail to the mail account. This is my script:

```
from imaplib import IMAP4_SSL
from getpass import getpass
mail = IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
mail.login('xxx@gmail.com',getpass())
mail.select("inbox")
while True:
    res, data = mail.uid("search", None,'ALL')
    print(res,data)
    raw_input()
```

Run the script, send a mail to the mail account, then press enter and I get:

```
('OK', ['11 12 13'])
('OK', ['11 12 13'])
```

The search result just remains unchanged, why and how to solve it?
Is this because of Gmail, IMAP protocol or imaplib?

Comment: Try doing a NOOP between.  This generally indicates to the server you're ready for new data, and usually gets the server to recheck against its backend database.

Comment: Does the email never show up until you logout and back in, or is it just that it takes longer to show up via IMAP than in inbox or searches on the webmail interface, or are you just checking immediately after sending and the email probably hasn’t been arrived yet?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the mail has arrived because I logged in by browser to confirm it. I'm searching `NOOP` now.

Comment: Really thanks! The `NOOP` command simply does the job! Great!

Comment: Useful link: [RFC3501-IMAP-NOOP](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3501#page-25), "the NOOP command can be used as a periodic poll for new messages or message status updates during a period of inactivity".